# Is there an 'umbrella' term that encompasses change and stasis?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing 'longitudinal' qualitative research, and to avoid continually being accused of assuming that I will find change, I need a term that covers both change and stasis - so I can say that I'm looking for instances of [change-or-stasis] in particular areas of experience over a particular period of time. One researcher gets round this by saying that stasis is a type of change, but I'm not sure that works. Any thoughts gratefully received!

Comment: Please explain how something that does not change and something that does can have a single referent?

Comment: If suppose you could consider "stasis is a type of change" as a corner case of zero change. But [this paper](https://www.ippapublicpolicy.org/file/paper/1433889589.pdf) is titled "Statis *and* Change." Can you not make it clear at the start what is being studied? You've said "to avoid continually being accused of assuming that I will find change." So phrase your work in such a way that it isn't presumptive.

Comment: [Synonym **stability**.](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stability)

Comment: .... behaviour?

Comment: **status over time** is the idiomatic way of expressing the idea in a succinct phrase.  You sure you don't want to add the `phrase request` tag? Analysis of that status will show either *continuity* or *discontinuity*.  But there's no commonly used or even rarely used word that encompasses both.. It's like looking for a *neutral and unbiased* word that can be a rubric for both "rough" and "smooth", "hardness" and "softness". You've gotta pick.  It's called the Rockwell Hardness measure, for example. So you can measure continuity and cite exceptions of discontinuity, or you can do the reverse.

Comment: Zero is a wind speed, and a rainfall amount. Stasis is a change status. You don't need another term to bring change and stasis together,

Comment: The accusation will not be levied against any term you choose, but by the way you phrase your statements. "This study attempts to determine the extent to which x influences y" implies influence. "This study attempts to determine to what extent x influences y" implies x may have no influence, but may have a measurable influence that can be stated.

Comment: "Variability" is a sciency-sounding word that you could put "low" or "high" in front of.

Comment: Another option is “the extent of variability over time.” And yet another is “the variability (if any) over time.” If you wish to strike a tone of learnedness, you could incorporate the linguistic term *diachronic*, though if you wish to be understood by normal people, then I’d give that one a pass.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about what exactly you are researching, but perhaps you could refer to the "continuity status" of each instance under review.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a situation changes or is at a standstill it is considered that all possibilities are part of its *evolution*. The word "evolution" is then a likely candidate, although, possibly not the only one.

> (SOED) **4 b** Any process of gradual change occurring in something, esp. from a simpler to a more complicated or advanced state; the passage of something through a succession of stages.